# How to interpret section 6.3.2.3 part 7 of the C11 standard?

Tags: c

In the context of another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002093/how-to-cast-the-address-of-a-pointer-generically-while-conforming-to-the-c-stand) there was some discussion on whether it was allowed (i.e. would or would not introduce implementation defined or undefined behavior) to cast `int**` to `void**` and subsequently assign a value to the dereferenced `void*`. This brings me to my question on the interpretation of the [C11 standard](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1169.pdf)

> 6.2.5 (28) A pointer to void shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as a pointer to a character type. ...
>   6.3.2.3 (1) A pointer to void may be converted to or from a pointer to any object type. A pointer to any object type may be converted to a pointer to void and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer.
>   6.3.2.3 (7) ... When a pointer to an object is converted to a pointer to a character type, the result points to the lowest addressed byte of the object. ...

My question is whether this

```
int* intptr = NULL;
void* dvoidptr = &intptr; /* 6.3.2.3 (1) */
*(void**)dvoidptr = malloc(sizeof *intptr); /* using 6.3.2.3 (1) */
```

conforms with the standard or not? It seems strange to me, but I cannot find a conclusive line of argument why not. `void*` to `void**` is guaranteed by 6.3.2.3 and 6.2.5 together with 6.3.2.3 help with the alignment.

Comment: This is just the same thing: it violates strict aliasing. End of story.

Comment: Where exactly is this specified in the standard? According to 6.2.5 (28) `void*` basically is a character type. And C11 Std. part 6.5 (7) explicitly says _An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of the following types: ..[list of types].. - a character type_. So maybe you should not be so fast in dismissing this question/discussion.

Comment: In C99, 6.5.7: the behavior is undefined if you access an object through an lvalue of incompatible type (except character types). Since `void *` is not `char *`, maybe you should not be so fast assuming things that aren't written in the standard.

Comment: and, btw, this is exactly what's written in the last paragraph of the answer. [Also, read this.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule)

Comment: I was in no way saying that it was not in the standard, only that people are more inclined to believe you if you were to use citations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code is not valid.

See the emphasis:

> 6.3.2.3 (1) A pointer to void may be converted to or from a pointer to any object type. A pointer to any object type may be converted to a pointer to void **and back again**; the result shall compare equal to **the original pointer**.

You are converting `int**` to `void*` (fine), and then to different type `void**` (not ok). C gives no quarantee that you can safely convert `void*` to anything other than the original type (aside from converting to `char *`)

In addition, `*(void**)dvoidptr` results in `void*` when in reality there is `int*`. What if, for example, `sizeof(void*) == 2` and `sizeof(int*) == 1`? You can *convert* `void*` pointer to other type, but you cannot *reinterpret* it directly as other type.

Comment: First of all thank you for the afford of not only saying its wrong that's it. 
Now to the comment: That is kind of the point, it is open to interpretation. The first sentence in 6.3.2.3 (1) says that I in fact can convert `void*` to `void**` (if `void*` can be interpreted as an object that is). Which leaves the question whether the rules are transitive or not. The argument with `sizeof(void*) > sizeof(int*)` seems wrong to me because of 6.3.2.3 (7) and 6.2.5 (28).

Comment: @merlin you think you are safe because you use a `void*` in between the two other pointers. That is not the case.

Comment: @merlin No, you can convert `void*` to `void**` *only* if pointer was originally `void**`, which in this case isn't. As for `sizeof` issue, point here is the *conversion*; pointers of different do not have to have same representation (except for `void*` and `char*`), when you assign to `void*` to other pointer type or back, it is compilers reponsibility insert code which coverts it to the other representation, if needed on that platform.